# How can my Rails app retrieve "www.monkey.com" from the request to display it in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to display the `"www.monkey.com"` part inside some view fields.

**But my app runs at different addresses:**

```
"www.monkey.com"
"www.hippo.com"
"www.giraffe.com"
```

How can I retrieve this name to display it in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically, `request.host` will do your job.

Answer (score 1):

You can access that data through the *response* and *request* objects, available within any controller action.  You can read a bit about them [here](http://rails.learnhub.com/lesson/6377-action-controller-the-request-and-response-objects).